# MySQL Case When (....., Interval 3 Day) for numbers instead of dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, case, intervals

I've got two questions here - 1) I'm trying to create a field which shows me a date - for example [30/05/2018] - I'm only taking out the day using

> `DATE_FORMAT(SetDate1.Value, '%e')`

, so field would be [30], and i would like the result of this new field to compare another day from another date field e.g 
[27/05/2018] - field is [27], and I'd like MySQL to let me know if the numbers (30 and 27) are equal or are 3 higher/lower than each other.
What I've tried is below, however it does not work on mySQL and I can't figure out why... any ideas? I need it to show me if 30/05/2018 with just 30 extracted, is either equal to, or 3 higher, or 3 lower than the number in the next field with just the day of month extracted.
My (not working) attempt is below -

> ,case when DATE_FORMAT(SetDate1.Value, '%e') >= (DATE_FORMAT(r.paydate, '%e'), - INTERVAL 3 DAY) then 'Rules Apply' else 'False' end as Rules

2) My second question is if there is an Interval function for numbers in general.

If I have a field with a number in it, e.g [4] and I want to compare it to another field and highlight if the number in the next field is equal to 4, one higher or one lower than 4, is there a specific mySQL function for this? I've tried to search for this but have been unable to find an answer.

Thanks

Comment: Pls ask a single question in a post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. if you read both questions, they're asking the same thing essentially so I didn't think it was necessary to ask the same or very similar questions separately. thanks

Comment: Nope, they are completely different questions. With dates you need to consider the year and month as well, while in case of numbers you do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, you should be using the `day()` function.  The logic is something like this:

```
abs(day(date1) - day(date2)) <= 3
```

That same logic will actually work on numbers as well (if you replace the `day()` expression with the number.